# Google Play Market alternative payment methods

Tags: android, payment, google-play

I'm from country where you can buy apps from Google Play Market, but you can not sell, e.g. if I create an app for android, I can only publish it to download for free. Can anybody suggest any alternative services or methods, how I can sell my apps?
Please think/suggest how would you do it?
Something like user downloads the app, pays through PayPal, app checks if payment was made and then app start...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a programming or programming-related question, so you may want to try an Android forum. But you should probably try your luck with the Amazon App Store if you're looking at 3rd party vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is against Google Play's ToS to use third party billing vendors like PayPal etc. You run the risk of having your account suspended if you do.

I started selling apps from India before it was officially supported. To do this, I registered an LLC in USA. I paid [LegalZoom](http://www.legalzoom.com/) ~$200 to take care of the registration etc. So far, its worked out pretty well for me, and I haven't felt the need to change this method even though India is now supported as a direct merchant.